# Object doesn't support property or method 'okToLaunchComposition' - issue in IE11 (Edge)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, adobe-edge, ie11-developer-tools

I have an embedded object that another developer created using Adobe Edge, this seems to work fine with Chrome & Firefox but IE11 doesn't (10 & 9 do.. I am not concerned for versions below this).

The error is as follows:

```
Object doesn't support property or method 'okToLaunchComposition'
File: Site_MAP_edgePreload.js, Line: 2, Column: 5086
```

Can anyone suggest the best way of fixing this to work in IE11 (while not breaking this so it still works in IE10/9 and Firefox & Chrome browsers.

This image below shows the function displayed within the console.log when I run window.AdobeEdge from within the Developer Tools console log.
http://s28.postimg.org/sqjdzu364/ie_11_adobe_edge.jpg

Full JS:

```js
/* Modified to hard-code the paths to the required JS files */
window.AdobeEdge=window.AdobeEdge||{};if(!AdobeEdge.yepnope){(function(o,e,H){function d(){for(var a=1,b=-1;k.length- ++b;)if(k[b].s&&!(a=k[b].r))break;a&&t()}function I(a){var b=e.createElement("script"),c;b.src=a.s;b.onreadystatechange=b.onload=function(){if(!c&&(!b.readyState||b.readyState=="loaded"||b.readyState=="complete"))c=1,d(),b.onload=b.onreadystatechange=null};g(function(){c||(c=1,d())},j.errorTimeout);a.e?b.onload():l.parentNode.insertBefore(b,l)}function J(a){var b=e.createElement("link"),c;b.href=a.s;b.rel="stylesheet";b.type="text/css";if(!a.e&&(u||v)){var n=function(a){g(function(){if(!c)try{a.sheet.cssRules.length?(c=1,d()):n(a)}catch(b){b.code==1E3||b.message=="security"||b.message=="denied"?(c=1,g(function(){d()},0)):n(a)}},0)};n(b)}else b.onload=function(){c||(c=1,g(function(){d()},0))},a.e&&b.onload();g(function(){c||(c=1,d())},j.errorTimeout);!a.e&&l.parentNode.insertBefore(b,l)}function t(){var a=k.shift();p=1;a?a.t?g(function(){a.t=="c"?J(a):I(a)},0):(a(),d()):p=0}function K(a,b,c,n,P,i){function B(){if(!q&&(!h.readyState||h.readyState=="loaded"||h.readyState=="complete"))m.r=q=1,!p&&d(),h.onload=h.onreadystatechange=null,g(function(){w.removeChild(h)},0)}var h=e.createElement(a),q=0,m={t:c,s:b,e:i};h.src=h.data=b;!x&&(h.style.display="none");h.width=h.height="0";if(a!="object")h.type=c;else if(/Firefox[\/\s](\d+\.\d+)/.test(navigator.userAgent))h.type="text/javascript";h.onload=h.onreadystatechange=B;if(a=="img")h.onerror=B;else if(a=="script")h.onerror=function(){m.e=m.r=1;t()};k.splice(n,0,m);w.insertBefore(h,x?null:l);g(function(){if(!q)w.removeChild(h),m.r=m.e=q=1,d()},j.errorTimeout)}function L(a,b,c){var e=b=="c"?M:C;p=0;b=b||"j";r(a)?K(e,a,b,this.i++,s,c):(k.splice(this.i++,0,a),k.length==1&&t());return this}function D(){var a=j;a.loader={load:L,i:0};return a}var s=e.documentElement,g=o.setTimeout,l=e.getElementsByTagName("script")[0],y={}.toString,k=[],p=0,v="MozAppearance"in s.style,x=v&&!!e.createRange().compareNode,w=x?s:l.parentNode,N=o.opera&&y.call(o.opera)=="[object Opera]",u="webkitAppearance"in s.style,O=u&&"async"in e.createElement("script"),C=v?"object":N||O?"img":"script",M=u?"img":C,E=Array.isArray||function(a){return y.call(a)=="[object Array]"},r=function(a){return typeof a=="string"},z=function(a){return y.call(a)=="[object Function]"},A=[],F={},G,j;j=function(a){function b(a){var a=a.split("!"),b=A.length,c=a.pop(),e=a.length,c={url:c,origUrl:c,prefixes:a},d,f;for(f=0;f<e;f++)(d=F[a[f]])&&(c=d(c));for(f=0;f<b;f++)c=A[f](c);return c}function c(a,c,e,d,g){var f=b(a),i=f.autoCallback;if(!f.bypass)if(c&&(c=z(c)?c:c[a]||c[d]||c[a.split("/").pop().split("?")[0]]),f.instead)return f.instead(a,c,e,d,g);else e.load(f.url,f.forceCSS||!f.forceJS&&/css$/.test(f.url)?"c":H,f.noexec),(z(c)||z(i))&&e.load(function(){D();c&&c(f.origUrl,g,d);i&&i(f.origUrl,g,d)})}function e(a,b){function d(a){if(r(a))c(a,f,b,0,g);else if(Object(a)===a)for(j in a)a.hasOwnProperty(j)&&c(a[j],f,b,j,g)}var g=!!a.test,i=a.load||a.both,f=a.callback,j;d(g?a.yep:a.nope);d(i);a.complete&&b.load(a.complete)}var d,i,g=this.yepnope.loader;if(r(a))c(a,0,g,0);else if(E(a))for(d=0;d<a.length;d++)i=a[d],r(i)?c(i,0,g,0):E(i)?j(i):Object(i)===i&&e(i,g);else Object(a)===a&&e(a,g)};j.addPrefix=function(a,b){F[a]=b};j.addFilter=function(a){A.push(a)};j.errorTimeout=1E4;if(e.readyState==null&&e.addEventListener)e.readyState="loading",e.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",G=function(){e.removeEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",G,0);e.readyState="complete"},0);o.yepnope=D()})(this,this.document);AdobeEdge.yepnope=window.yepnope}(function(compId){var htFallbacks;var testEle=document.createElement("div");function isSupported(a){var d=testEle.style,e;for(i=0;i<a.length;i++)if(e=a[i],d[e]!==void 0)return!0;return!1}function supportsRGBA(){testEle.cssText="background-color:rgba(150,255,150,.5)";if((""+testEle.style.backgroundColor).indexOf("rgba")==0)return!0;return!1}var hasTransform=isSupported(["transformProperty","WebkitTransform","MozTransform","OTransform","msTransform"]),hasSVG=!!document.createElementNS&&!!document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg","svg").createSVGRect,hasRGBA=supportsRGBA(),hasJSON=window.JSON&&window.JSON.parse&&window.JSON.stringify,readyToPlay=!1;function safeColor(a){a=""+a;if(!hasRGBA&&a.indexOf("rgba")==0){var d=a.lastIndexOf(",");d>0&&(a="rgb("+a.substring(5,d)+")")}return a}AdobeEdge._preloaders=AdobeEdge._preloaders||[];AdobeEdge._preloaders.push(function(){filesToLoad&&(loadResources(filesToLoad),filesToLoad=void 0)});function doLoadResources(){for(var a=0;a<AdobeEdge._preloaders.length;a++)AdobeEdge._preloaders[a]()}AdobeEdge._readyplayers=AdobeEdge._readyplayers||[];AdobeEdge._readyplayers.push(function(){readyToPlay&&AdobeEdge.okToLaunchComposition(compId)});function playWhenReady(){AdobeEdge._playWhenReady=!0;for(var a=0;a<AdobeEdge._readyplayers.length;a++)AdobeEdge._readyplayers[a]()}function edgeCallback(a){htFallbacks[a]&&(a=htFallbacks[a]);AdobeEdge.preload.got[a]=!0;if(a==AdobeEdge.preload.last)!AdobeEdge.bootstrapLoading||AdobeEdge._playWhenReady?AdobeEdge.okToLaunchComposition(compId):readyToPlay=!0,AdobeEdge.preload.busy=!1,AdobeEdge.preload.q.length>0&&(a=AdobeEdge.preload.q.pop(),AdobeEdge.requestResources(a.files,a.callback))}AdobeEdge.requestResources=AdobeEdge.requestResources||function(a,d){AdobeEdge.yepnope.errorTimeout=4E3;AdobeEdge.preload.busy=!0;AdobeEdge.preload.got=AdobeEdge.preload.got||{};var e,b=a.length,h=[],c;for(e=0;e<b;e++){c=a[e];if(typeof c==="string")url=c,c={load:url};else if(url=c.yep||c.load,c.callback){var k=c.callback;c.callback=function(a,b,c){k(a,b,c)&&d(a,b,c)}}if(!c.callback)c.callback=d;if(!AdobeEdge.preload.got[url])h.push(c),AdobeEdge.preload.last=url}h.length&&AdobeEdge.yepnope(h)};var filesToLoad,dlContent,preContent,doDelayLoad,signaledLoading,loadingEvt,requiresSVG,htLookup={},aLoader,aEffectors;function loadResources(a,d){AdobeEdge.preload=AdobeEdge.preload||[];AdobeEdge.preload.q=AdobeEdge.preload.q||[];d||!isCapable()?filesToLoad=a:AdobeEdge.preload.busy?AdobeEdge.preload.q.push({files:a,callback:edgeCallback}):AdobeEdge.requestResources(a,edgeCallback)}function splitUnits(a){var d={};d.num=parseFloat(a);if(typeof a=="string")d.units=a.match(/[a-zA-Z%]+$/);if(d.units&&typeof d.units=="object")d.units=d.units[0];return d}function defaultUnits(a){var d=a;if(a!=="auto"&&(a=splitUnits(a),!a||!a.units))d+="px";return d}function findNWC(a,d){if(String(a.className).indexOf(d)!=-1)return a;for(var e=a.childNodes,b=0;b<e.length;b++){var h=findNWC(e[b],d);if(h!=!1)return h}return!1}function simpleContent(a,d,e){var b=document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0],e=e||findNWC(b,compId),h,c,k,g;if(e){if(e.style.position!="absolute"&&e.style.position!="relative")e.style.position="relative"}else e=b;for(var m=0;m<a.length;m++){b=a[m];b.type=="image"?(h=document.createElement("img"),h.src=b.fill[1]):h=document.createElement("div");h.id=b.id;g=h.style;if(b.type=="text"){if(c=b.font){if(c[0]&&c[0]!=="")g.fontFamily=c[0];typeof c[1]!="object"&&(c[1]=[c[1]]);c[1][1]||(c[1][1]="px");if(c[1][0]&&c[1][0]!=="")g.fontSize=c[1][0]+c[1][1];if(c[2]&&c[2]!=="")g.color=safeColor(c[2]);if(c[3]&&c[3]!=="")g.fontWeight=c[3];if(c[4]&&c[4]!=="")g.textDecoration=b.font[4];if(c[5]&&c[5]!=="")g.fontStyle=b.font[5]}if(b.align&&b.align!="auto")g.textAlign=b.align;if(b.position)g.position=b.position;if((!b.rect[2]||b.rect[2]<=0)&&(!b.rect[3]||b.rect[3]<=0))g.whiteSpace="nowrap";h.innerHTML=b.text}if(d)h.className=d;g.position="absolute";c=b.rect[0];k=b.rect[1];if(b.transform&&b.transform[0]){var j=b.transform[0][0],f=splitUnits(j);if(f&&f.units&&(j=f.num,f.units=="%"&&b.rect[2])){var f=b.rect[2],l=splitUnits(b.rect[2]);if(l&&l.units)f=l.num,l.units=="%"&&(f=f/100*e.offsetWidth);j=j/100*f;e.offsetWidth>0&&(j=j/e.offsetWidth*100)}if(f=splitUnits(c))c=f.num;c+=j;if(!f.units)f.units="px";c+=f.units;if(b.transform[0].length>1){j=b.transform[0][1];if((f=splitUnits(j))&&f.units)if(j=f.num,f.units=="%"&&b.rect[3]){f=b.rect[3];if((l=splitUnits(b.rect[3]))&&l.units)f=l.num,l.units=="%"&&(f=f/100*e.offsetHeight);j=j/100*f;e.offsetHeight>0&&(j=j/e.offsetHeight*100)}if(f=splitUnits(k))k=f.num;k+=j;if(!f.units)f.units="px";k+=f.units}}g.left=defaultUnits(c);g.top=defaultUnits(k);g.width=defaultUnits(b.rect[2]);g.height=defaultUnits(b.rect[3]);if(b.linkURL)htLookup[h.id]=b,h.onclick=function(){var a=htLookup[this.id];a.linkTarget?window.open(a.linkURL,a.linkTarget):window.location.href=a.linkURL},g.cursor="pointer";e.appendChild(h);if(b.c)for(g=0;g<b.c.length;g++)simpleContent(b.c[g],d,h)}}var fnCycle=function(a){a?fnCycle&&setTimeout(fnCycle,20):a={event:"loading",progress:0};loadingEvt&&loadingEvt(a)},aBootcompsLoaded=[];if(!window.AdobeEdge.bootstrapListeners)window.AdobeEdge.bootstrapListeners=[];window.AdobeEdge.bootstrapCallback=function(a){window.AdobeEdge.bootstrapListeners.push(a);if(aBootcompsLoaded.length>0)for(var d=0;d<aBootcompsLoaded.length;d++)a(aBootcompsLoaded[d])};if(!window.AdobeEdge.preloadComplete)window.AdobeEdge.preloadComplete={};window.AdobeEdge.preloadComplete[compId]=function(a){AdobeEdge.$_(".edgePreload"+a).css("display","none");fnCycle=null;loadingEvt&&loadingEvt({event:"done",progress:1,reason:"complete"});aBootcompsLoaded.push(a);for(var d=window.AdobeEdge.bootstrapListeners.length,e=0;e<d;e++)try{window.AdobeEdge.bootstrapListeners[e](a)}catch(b){console.log("bootstrap error "+b)}};function isCapable(){if(hasTransform){if(requiresSVG&&!hasSVG)return!1;return!0}return!1}function onDocLoaded(){window.AdobeEdge.loaded=!0;fnCycle({event:"begin"});isCapable()?(preContent&&preContent.dom&&simpleContent(preContent.dom,"edgePreload"+compId),filesToLoad&&!signaledLoading&&(loadResources(filesToLoad),filesToLoad=void 0)):dlContent&&dlContent.dom&&(loadingEvt&&loadingEvt({event:"done",progress:1,reason:"downlevel"}),simpleContent(dlContent.dom))};window.AdobeEdge=window.AdobeEdge||{};window.AdobeEdge.framework='jquery';if(document.addEventListener){window.addEventListener("load",onDocLoaded,false)}else if(document.attachEvent){window.attachEvent("onload",onDocLoaded)}requiresSVG=true;doDelayLoad=false;htFallbacks={"edge_includes/jquery-1.7.1.min.js":"http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"};aLoader=[{load:"http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js",callback:function(result,key){if(!window.jQuery){yepnope({load:"edge_includes/jquery-1.7.1.min.js",callback:edgeCallback});return false}return true}},{load:"/js/Site_MAP/edge_includes/edge.1.5.0.min.js"},{load:"/js/Site_MAP/Site_MAP_edge.js"},{load:"/js/Site_MAP/Site_MAP_edgeActions.js"}];if(AdobeEdge.bootstrapLoading){signaledLoading=true;AdobeEdge.loadResources=doLoadResources;AdobeEdge.playWhenReady=playWhenReady}loadResources(aLoader,doDelayLoad);preContent={dom:[]};dlContent={dom:[]}})("EDGE-148673301");
```

Comment: any piece of code will be helpful

Comment: your js code doesn't have the definition of `okToLaunchComposition`. It must be in some other file, does it have any other dependencies ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this working following this link - in a nutshell I had to update the yepnode to the 1.5.4 version that is displayed within the Site_MAP_edgePreload.js.

Once saved & after doing a force refresh this now works in IE 11 as well as 10 & 9.

https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1242630?start=0&tstart=0